# Convert logit coefficient confidence interval to odds ratio in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I've run a simple logit model in another program, and brought over the resulting coefficient and CI into R to plot.

To convert the logit into an odds ratio, I think I need to use `d$oddsratio <-  exp(d$logitcoef)/(1+exp(d$logitcoef))`. But how would I then go about calculating the confidence interval for the odds ratio as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty common practice in epidemiological circles and accordingly there is a package for that!

```
install.packages("epiDisplay")
library(epiDisplay)

glm_mod <- glm(c1~c2 +c3, family=binomial, data=df) #whatever you are running
logistic.display(glm_mod)
```

The output will be a set of odds ratios and confidence intervals including Wald's Tests and P-Values for each of your included variables and interactions.

It is pretty straight forward.